# Conditional by field and category

Tags: channel-entries, categories

I'm trying to get this if statement to work, not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is my code:

```
{categories}{if remaining_places_available<1 && category_id==259}<p><strong>Fully booked</strong></p>{/if}{/categories}
```

This is within the channel entries tag. the remaining_places_available is a field. Replacing && with AND doesn't work either. It's just outputting {categories} {/categories}  on the front end.

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks,
Julie

EDIT: This is my channel entries tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="choices_events" show_future_entries="yes" show_expired="no" disable="trackbacks" orderby="date_time" sort="asc" paginate="bottom" status="open" dynamic="no" parse="inward"}
```

This works fine in my code, and outputs '259' on the correct entries:

```
{categories}
    {if category_id == "259"}259{/if}
{/categories}
```

I just can't get it to work within the other if statement :

```
{categories}{if remaining_places_available<1 && category_id==259}<p><strong>Fully booked</strong></p>{/if}{/categories}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? You may have the categories disabled in your `channel:entries` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say that "trackbacks" isn't a value of the parameter disable anymore.

Now, let's make your conditionals to work.

I didn't realize until see your code, but looks like just the variables related to the {categories} tag pair are available inside it.

Since, your conditional uses an "AND", we can break it into two parts:

```
{if remaining_places_available < 1}
    {categories}
        {if category_id == 259}<p><strong>Fully booked</strong></p>{/if}
    {/categories}
{/if}
```